# Wedding Day Minhagim for Him

Tags: minhag, wedding

What are some Minhagim that men are accustomed or unaccustomed to do on the day of the their wedding? 
Can you please list the minhag with its source, thanks.

Comment: Mazel Tov on your upcoming big day, and may you be zocheh to building a Bayis Ne’eman BiYisrael. That said, this question is too broad; maybe you can edit to narrow in on specific types of minhagim? (Of course, for your own wedding day you should talk with your Rav as to what minhagim you should do.)

Comment: Leaving as a comment because I don't have sources (other than seeing people do this): going to the graves of tzaddikim or to holy sites like the Kotel/Har Habayit to pray, Sephardic people often make lists of people who need refuot and yeshuot and pray for those people, going to the mikveh, fasting all day, going to get a bracha from a rabbi.